# Creating random combinations of objects, a group of objects or collections

Tags: objects, add-on, procedural, collections, random

Consider 10 shirts, 10 pants and 10 shoes. Is there any way in blender I can quickly make a copy of all and make random combinations of all, each combination containing exactly one shirt, one pant and one pair of shoes, and store them in a separate group / collections using any tool, inbuilt function, geonodes, scripts or even addons within blender?

Basically this is a random character build / clothing generator.

NOTE: I know basic programming, but have never done any scripting in blender, a noob in that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all are you asking for random permutations? or simply all possible combinations? It sounds like you are looking for the set of all permutations.

This sounds like a job for scripting. It's just a matter of making sure all objects will fit each other.

Let's just work with 3 items instead of 10 (because it's too much to print 1000 items as you ask for). Say you have all you objects in a matrix:

```
all_cloth_items = []
for cloth in ["shirts", "pants", "shoes"]:
    cloth_item = []
    for i in range(0,3):
        cloth_item.append(f"{cloth}_{i}")
    all_cloth_items.append(cloth_item)
print(all_cloth_items)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ['shirts_0', 'shirts_1', 'shirts_2'],
    ['pants_0', 'pants_1', 'pants_2'],
    ['shoes_0', 'shoes_1', 'shoes_2']
]
```

These objects could be blend files on you side for example.

Itertools will let you find all permutations.

```
import itertools
shirts, pants, shoes = all_cloth_items
for x, shape,color in itertools.product(shirts, pants, shoes):
    print(f"{x} {shape} {color}")
```

Prints:

```
shirts_0 pants_0 shoes_0
shirts_0 pants_0 shoes_1
shirts_0 pants_0 shoes_2
shirts_0 pants_1 shoes_0
shirts_0 pants_1 shoes_1
shirts_0 pants_1 shoes_2
shirts_0 pants_2 shoes_0
shirts_0 pants_2 shoes_1
shirts_0 pants_2 shoes_2
shirts_1 pants_0 shoes_0
shirts_1 pants_0 shoes_1
shirts_1 pants_0 shoes_2
shirts_1 pants_1 shoes_0
shirts_1 pants_1 shoes_1
shirts_1 pants_1 shoes_2
shirts_1 pants_2 shoes_0
shirts_1 pants_2 shoes_1
shirts_1 pants_2 shoes_2
shirts_2 pants_0 shoes_0
shirts_2 pants_0 shoes_1
shirts_2 pants_0 shoes_2
shirts_2 pants_1 shoes_0
shirts_2 pants_1 shoes_1
shirts_2 pants_1 shoes_2
shirts_2 pants_2 shoes_0
shirts_2 pants_2 shoes_1
shirts_2 pants_2 shoes_2
```

Now it is just a matter of using the blender python library `bpy` to import, set, and save the files found by itertools.

**Edit**

Just saw you note, that you have never tried blender `bpy` before. I would advise you to try and split the task up in smaller tasks.

Now we learned how to get the permutations. But you need to learn how to:

- Import files/objects/collections with `bpy`
- Combine files/objects/collections with `bpy`
- save/render files with `bpy`

Try to do these individually before worrying doing everything at once. This site is amazing to answer simple and small tasks if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks may i make a change in my question? in addition to storing them in a separate group can you have them combine into one object as well?  Also it has been a hot minute since i've programed, can you explain to me what's happening? I see you're appending items into a 3x 3 array, but how does blender know what functions to use if you haven't defined them?

Comment: I assume you have a 3x10 array of blend files to import right? (10 shirts, 10 shoes, 10 pants). Then use the result from itertools to make a loop. For example, the first itteration would import shirts_0.blend pants_0.blend shoes_0.blend and save / render it  somewhere.

I didn't provide any code related to blender in my example.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this... also, i'm sorry, i should have specified, all 10 files are within one blender file itself, can it still be achieved ? or is it required to be in separate files?

Comment: I would advise you to move them into their own blend file, since if you try and make 10^3 combinations in the same blend file it will get messy. Here it is discussed how to append blend files together: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256447/is-there-a-way-to-merge-multiple-blend-files